# error in copying a file: 'cp: cannot lseek'

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, cp

I'm on a Debian derivative (RPi OS/bookworm). I am trying to copy a rather large *image file* (`.img`), approximately 9-10 GB from the Synology NAS (`btrfs` filesystem) to a local folder (`ext4` filesystem). There is plenty of space on the local drive, and I successfully copied another, even larger, file just minutes previously.  I'm using a cifs mount for the NAS

Here's what I see:

```shellsession
pi@rpi5:~/image-files$ cp /mnt/SynologyNAS/rpi_share/raspberrypi5/20240109_Pi5_imagebackup.img ./
cp: cannot lseek '/mnt/SynologyNAS/rpi_share/rpi5/20240109_Pi5_imagebackup.img': Input/output error
```

I've tried "reversing" the direction; i.e. `cd /mnt/SynologyNAS/rpi_share/rpi5`, but the result is the same:

```shellsession
pi@rpi5:/mnt/SynologyNAS/rpi_share/rpi5$ cp 20240109_Pi5_imagebackup.img /home/pi/image-files
cp: cannot lseek '20240109_Pi5_imagebackup.img': Input/output error
```

I can copy a small text file:

```shellsession
pi@rpi5:/mnt/SynologyNAS/rpi_share/rpi5$ cp -pv 20240109_Pi5_imagebackup.txt ~/image-files
'20240109_Pi5_imagebackup.txt' -> '/home/pi/image-files/20240109_Pi5_imagebackup.txt'
```

If it makes any difference, the NAS has a `btrfs` file system. I've done a search on this error, but get nothing that appears relevant.

Is there a work-around to this? I need to get this image file in my local folder.

##### EDIT:

I found one workaround: `gzip` the image file & it copies fine. I don't know whether the `cannot lseek` error has something to do with the fact that this is an image file, or if it's just based on size. The `gzip` file is on the order of 3.5 GB.

Comment: The file system does not care whether it's an image file or cat pictures or a giant log file. So that's not an explanation.

Comment: What did dmesg say when the error occurred? This sounds like a storage device problem, and I have little trust that your gzipped file is intact.

Comment: It would help if you said what is the size of the file & what the target file system is.  Also, in such cases, I would be copying it to /dev/null just to ensure it can be read through to the target device.

Comment: @Bib: Addressed your cmt re file systems in an edit to the Q.

Comment: This sounds like the 32-bit limit on filesizes. Is this a 32-bit OS on the rPi? (the filesystem on a 32-bit OS will happily support files larger than 4Gb, but I don't think cifs will)